# Можно ли с помощью .net сделать фото с фотоаппарата? (не web-камера)

Tags: c#, камера

Появилась производственная необходимость делать фото программно, web-камеры не подходят, т.к. у них низкое качество изображения. Найти в гугл информацию по поводу того можно ли программно с помощью того C# заставить фотоаппарат сделать фото не нашёл. Слышал про производственные фотоаппараты, но ничего опять же о них не нашёл в сети. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от конкретной камеры:

1. Если камера мобильная, то можно написать приложение на Xamarin.
2. Если камера подключена к ПК, то тут все зависит уже от API предоставляемым ПО или драйвером камеры. Если таковое API есть, то это легко реализуется, в противном случае придется писать свой драйвер, чего на .NET, вроде, сделать нельзя.